# TwitterSettings.OAuthVersion

Tags: windows-phone

i don't understand that : [GetRequestToken is not working in TweetSharp on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207773/getrequesttoken-is-not-working-in-tweetsharp-on-windows-phone/19243676#19243676)

My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp2.Resources;
using TweetSharp;
namespace PhoneApp2
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private const string consumerKey = "zvBvaKjEQRwGqu9ECaNfop0pr";
    private const string consumerSecret = "SgEqsMRcIrEYNrtXhvtYdnx7qBA9EITzswneyjf8wRorDvSAvn";
    private TwitterService myclient;
    private OAuthRequestToken requestToken;
    private bool userAuthenticated = false;

    // Constructeur
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myclient = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //If user is already logged in, just send the tweet, otherwise get the RequestToken
        if (userAuthenticated)
            //send the Tweet, this is just a placeholder, we will add the actual code later
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { MessageBox.Show("Placeholder for tweet sending"); });
        else
            myclient.GetRequestToken(processRequestToken);
    }

    private void processRequestToken(OAuthRequestToken token, TwitterResponse response)
    {
        if (token == null)
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { MessageBox.Show("Error getting request token"); });
        else
        {
            requestToken = token;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                Browser.Navigate(myclient.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken));
            });
        }
    }




}
}
```

and visual studio 2013 create an error on `myclient.GetRequestToken(processRequestToken);` ...

how can incorporate your solution with hammock on my code?

Answer (score 0):

I had this identical error last week ([doing this app)](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/oh-4th-july/1e40d0e7-140b-45cb-9892-cfdf3ae5158a) The solution was to implement the Hammock Library instead of tweet sharp. Also in the post tweet example change the version from 1 to 1.1

[This is the Nokia Developer Documentation I followed to implement logging in](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Twitter%3a_OAuth_1.0_Authentication_using_Hammock)

[This is the Nokia Developer Documentation I followed to implement posting a tweet](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Twitter%3a_Posting_Tweets_using_Hammock)

REMEMBER CHANGE THE VERSION TO 1.1 LIKE THIS

From this

```
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
            {
                Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
                SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
                ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
                Token = this.accessToken,
                TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
                Version = "1.0"
            };

            var restClient = new RestClient
            {
                Authority = "http://api.twitter.com",
                HasElevatedPermissions = true
            };

            var restRequest = new RestRequest
            {
                Credentials = credentials,
                Path = "/1/statuses/update.json",
                Method = WebMethod.Post
            };

            restRequest.AddParameter("status", txtTweetContent.Text);
            restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
```

To This

```
 var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
            {
                Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
                SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
                ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
                Token = this.accessToken,
                TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
                Version = "1.0"
            };

            var restClient = new RestClient
            {
                Authority = "http://api.twitter.com",
                HasElevatedPermissions = true
            };

            var restRequest = new RestRequest
            {
                Credentials = credentials,
                Path = "/1.1/statuses/update.json",
                Method = WebMethod.Post
            };

            restRequest.AddParameter("status", txtTweetContent.Text);
            restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
```